# Cell Image layout constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am having trouble centering the image on my table row. I want to make sure I center an image consistently across all iOS devices. So I made a custom cell, that has a basic image view.

```
        - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
        {
            self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
            if (self) {
                // Initialization code

                float imgWidth = 250;

                float imgHeight = 250;
                self.showImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2)-(imgWidth/2),0,imgWidth,imgHeight)];
     [self.contentView addSubview:self.showImage];
    }
    return self;
}
```

So In my cell for row at index path method contains the following constraint.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   SponsorCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"sponsorCell"];

        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[SponsorCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"sponsorCell"];
        }


///....Arithmetic for processing image and other data... 

         image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pdfPath];

                  [cell.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:0 toItem:cell.showImage attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0]];
            [cell.showImage setImage:image];

            cell.showImage.accessibilityLabel =accessibilityLabel;

    }
```

When I execute the code,

I get the following exception:

```
7:26:57.789 Demo[56438:21023305] Exception: Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal
```

From other stack over flow posts, I am understanding that I need to add constraints to a higher level such as the tableview. Is my understanding correct? I can add constraints just fine in the xib, I just am having a rough time programatically. Could someone please explain what is wrong in my approach/thinking? Would really like to learn from this. Hopefully I am clear. An example would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could try to change constraintWithItem:cell to constraintWithItem:cell.contentView, if that doesnt work: Have you made a xib for the custom cell? Or is only code? Before adding the constraint the imageView must be added as subview. to contentView

Comment: That got rid of the error! But it still is not centered. Any ideas? :)

Comment: Only code for cell. No xib. The only xib I have is for the tableview.

Comment: I am pretty sure I am already adding the image to the content view in my custom code by calling [self.contentview addsubView:showImage]

Comment: You should also set constraints for its width and height

Answer (score 0):

Wow.. I managed to figure it out. Here's what I did:

```
   customImageView  = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            customImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

            [cell.contentView addSubview:customImageView];


            image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pdfPath];



            [customImageView setImage:image];

           [cell.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:0 toItem:customImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

            [cell.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:cell.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:0 toItem:customImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
```

Works beautifully. Word of caution, be sure autoResizingMaskingIntoConstraints is set to NO;